# Why is there a pause between animation loops here?

Tags: react-native

I've updated this post in the hope someone gets wind of it. I've managed to get the loop working (with help @Ariel Perez) but now it is pausing between each loop.

Here's what happens:

I have an animation that plays through all images, then once that is done, it loops continuously over the last few frames. All the while the user is holding down the screen. As the loop begins, it plays the 15 frames, then pauses for about a second, then plays again, continuing on. I'm trying to get rid of the pause!

Here are the animation functions:

```
export default class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state = {

    isOn:false, 
    mouseUp: null,
    isMouseDown: null,
    stateImages: Images,

  }

  this.animations = new Animated.Value(0);
  this.opacity = [];
  Images.map((item, index) => {

    this.opacity.push(
       this.animations.interpolate({
            inputRange: [index - 1, index, index + 1],
            outputRange: [0, 100, 0],

        }),
      )
    })

// The animation loop function

startAnimation = () => {

  Animated.timing(this.animations, {
    toValue: length - 1,
    duration: 50 * length,
    easing: Easing.linear,
    useNativeDriver: true,
  }).start(({ finished }) => {
    // completion callback

    if (this.state.isMouseDown === true) {
      this.startLoopAnimation();
    }
  });
}

// The animation loop function
startLoopAnimation = () => {
  this.animations = new Animated.Value(0);
    this.opacity = [];
    Images.map((item, index) => {

      this.opacity.push(
        this.animations.interpolate({
           inputRange: [index - 1, index, index + 1],
           outputRange: [0, 100, 200], //adding 200 here keeps the frame rendered but doesn't stop the pause.
      }),
     )
   })

  let orderedImages = Images.slice(Images.length - 15, Images.length);

    this.setState({
      stateImages: orderedImages,
    });
  Animated.timing(this.animations, {
    toValue: length - 1,
    duration: 50 * length,
    easing: Easing.linear,
    useNativeDriver: true,
  }).start(({ finished }) => {

    // completion callback
     if(this.state.isMouseDown === true){

      this.startLoopAnimation(); //this loops the animations last 15 frames

     }

  });
}

onItemMouseDown = () => {

  this.startAnimation() //This starts the entire animation

  this.setState({
  isMouseDown: true,
  isOn: true,
  pauseToggle: 'down',
  mouseUp: 'no',
  twoSecOver: false,

}, () => {
  console.log(this.state.isMouseDown, 'isMouseDown')

})

 this.timer = setInterval(() => {
   this.setState(prevState => ({
     time: prevState.time + 1
      }))
    }, 1000)

  }

onItemMouseUp = () => {
  this.setState({
    stateImages: Images,
    isMouseDown: false,
    isOn:false,
    mouseUp: 'yes',


  },() => {
  console.log(this.state.isMouseDown, 'isMouseDown')
  // console.log(this.state.stateImages, 'stateImages on mouseup')


})
```

and the render:

```
render() { //the render shows an image which the user can press on. This then shows the animation.

  return (
    <ImageBackground source={background} style={styles.background}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.background}
        onPressIn={this.onItemMouseDown}
        onPressOut={this.onItemMouseUp}
      >

      </TouchableOpacity>

      {this.state.isOn === true ? (
        <View style={styles.background}>

      <Text style={styles.timer}>{this.state.time}</Text>

        {this.state.stateImages.map((item, index) => {
            const opacity = this.opacity[index];

            return (
              <Animated.View
                key={item.id}
                style={[styles.anim, { animations: item, opacity}]}
              >
              <Image source={item.source} style={styles.animImage}/>
              </Animated.View>

            );
          })}

        </View>
      ) : null}

    </ImageBackground>
  );
 }
```

Can anyone spot anything that could cause this pause or even suggest a better way to loop through frames?

Comment: there is no problem in my side you can check https://streamable.com/n0jpj0

Comment: Your animation doesn't loop through the last 15 frames, by the looks of it. It's also too fast to see if there would be a pause between loops.

Comment: You can see the pause here:
https://streamable.com/315x8j
The numbers are just a counter to show you how long these annoying pauses show.

Comment: Counter is wrong becasue that counter do not attch with images counter it useless for now

Comment: Yeah I know - the counter isn't supposed to be attached to images, it's there for other reasons. Do you know of any way to reduce or eliminate the pause?

Comment: @Muhammad this is not helping. Can you either move to chat and help or please move on. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: yes we can move to chat

Comment: Not sure how to move this to chat by the way!

Comment: If we go into chat it won't be visible to everyone. I suppose if we keep commenting it will give us a suggestion to move into chat.

Comment: Here's another comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215815/discussion-between-tom-and-muhammad-numan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a problem in `duration` because after splitting 15 images then you should be minus 15 from the length

```
const length2 = Images.length-15;
```

```
 Animated.timing(this.animations, {
    toValue: length2 - 1,
    duration: 40 * length2, //here was the problem
    easing: Easing.linear,
    useNativeDriver: true,
  })
```

Comment: Even though the pause wasn't completely eliminated,
Muhammad worked with me to reduce it. Thanks again.